# Input and button have a margin even though none is applied - html css

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to place an input next to a button and even though i have removed all margin there is still a gap between the elements.

```css
#searchButton {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2.4em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #71b066;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#searchBox {
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 1px #dbdada solid !important;
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<form id="formBox">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="searchBox">
  <button type="submit" id="searchButton">OK</button>
</form>
```

I have tested this on Google chrome and Firefox and within a jsFiddle. I get the same result everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to the input/button container as show below

For the record, I wouldn't style an `id` but add a `class` instead.

[Here's a good introduction to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#searchButton {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2.4em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #71b066;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#searchBox {
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 1px #dbdada solid !important;
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}

#formBox {
  display: flex;
}


/* flex is your friend! */
```

```html
<form id="formBox">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="searchBox">
  <button type="submit" id="searchButton">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but why does adding flex solve this problem? I will accept answer in 5 minutes when SO lets me.

Comment: Read up about it, it's too much to explain here how it works - I've added a link which is a good intro

Comment: @DavidBenz an introduction to flexbox won't explain your issue, check the duplicate